# Want to remove time from date in gridview but i used data-adapter and data table

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

```
            con.Open();
        DataTable d = new DataTable();
        adp = new SqlDataAdapter("select tender_register.tender_no,tender_register.date_of_work_order,tender_register.stipulated_date_of_completion,contractor_info.name,contractor_info.phone_no from tender_register,contractor_info where tender_register.tender_no=contractor_info.tender_no AND tender_register.stipulated_date_of_completion between @startDate AND @endDate ", con);
        adp.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("startDate", TextBox1.Text);
        adp.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("endDate",TextBox2.Text);
        adp.Fill(d);
        GridView1.DataSource = d;
        GridView1.DataBind();
        con.Close();
```

this looks like this

[image]

I want to remove that timing from date column can i remove it and how?

**this is html code**

```
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
    From : <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox><img src="../img/calender.png" />&ensp;&ensp;
    To : <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox><img src="../img/calender.png" />
    &ensp;<asp:Button ID="submit" Text="submit" runat="server" OnClick="submit_Click" />
    <br /><br />
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server">          
    </asp:GridView>

    <br />
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: Could you show GridView's markup inside ASPX page?

Comment: My html code contains only          **<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server"></asp:GridView>**  Should i have to add something in this ?

Comment: I would like to see how you are populating that date field inside GridView.

Comment: i am using data adapter and then just fill data table by using adp.fill(d). then just allocating dataGridview.DataSource=d; to populate records from database. I am not using any other formating for gridview. It is just default settings after assigning data table to gridview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks, but got a solution.

1. Create a view by selecting fields from different tables and save the view
2. In query, select columns from view and also pass there parameters for between clause
3. Now bind data source to gridview
4. now add data format to boundfield
5. see the result.

Another way is :

write `convert(varchar(15), column name, 103) as '[name you want to display as heading]'` in query and just fill datatable and add it as datasource to gridview. It will give same result without using boundfield.

Answer (score 1):

**Just try this:**

this is for itemtemplate

```
 con.Open();
  DataTable d = new DataTable();
  adp = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT TR.tender_no,TR.date_of_work_order,TR.stipulated_date_of_completion,CI.NAME,CI.phone_no FROM tender_register as TR inner join contractor_info as CI on TR.tender_no = CI.tender_no WHERE TR.stipulated_date_of_completion Between @startDate and @endDate ", con);
  adp.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("startDate", TextBox1.Text);
  adp.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("endDate",TextBox2.Text);
  adp.Fill(d);
  mainGrid.DataSource = d;
  mainGrid.DataBind();
  con.Close();

 <asp:GridView ID="mainGrid" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" CssClass="table table-bordered table-condensed table-hover" OnRowDataBound="mainGrid_RowDataBound" AllowPaging="True" ForeColor="Black">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="tender No" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblaa" Text=' <%# Eval("tender_no") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="From Date" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lbltiming2" Text=' <%# Eval("date_of_work_order","{0:MM-dd-yyyy}") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="To Date" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lbltiming1" Text=' <%# Eval("stipulated_date_of_completion","{0:MM-dd-yyyy}") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="NAME" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lbltiming" Text=' <%# Eval("NAME") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="phone_no" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblstatus" Text=' <%# Eval("phone_no") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>                                        
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

**And this is for DataBound Field**

```
<asp:GridView ID="mainGrid" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" CssClass="table table-bordered table-condensed table-hover" OnRowDataBound="mainGrid_RowDataBound" AllowPaging="True" ForeColor="Black">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="date_of_work_order" HeaderText="From Date" DataFormatString = "{0:d}"   ReadOnly="True" />                              
        <asp:BoundField DataField="stipulated_date_of_completion" HeaderText="To Date" DataFormatString = "{0:d}"   ReadOnly="True" />                                    
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Comment: where to add this template field ???   the CAST tag is not working in query

Comment: in this way you can add template field in gridview

Comment: and if I used Boundfield so i can set dataformat of date then how to join or fetching data from two tables and selected fields only using datasource?

Comment: I think this is your answer which your looking for.

Comment: How to show data from two different tables and selected columns only using this template? please tell me the code if possible. I am trying to get data of selected fields from two different tables and want to format that date field by showing date only.

Comment: if u use the boundfield etc I unabe to find option for selection of columns from two different tables.If I select only one table then I found option to select column which generates boundfield for modifying format of date.

Comment: then try to inner join by the query to use the gridview for two tables if two tables don't have any conman columns then gridview will not bind

Comment: and the code is as shown above in that gridview i have bind three table by inner joining it and getting the fields that i want to display in gridview

Comment: could you please post that code so i can get an idea

Comment: wait i will send u some demo

Comment: sure I will like to refer it

Comment: just check it now